# Vue-Cli create project failed

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-4

**Emenvironment**

- Windows 10 wsl -> Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- node v8.10.0
- npm v6.14.4
- Vue CLI v4.3.1

**Scene**

When I use `vue create my-project` to create a new project, I select the following options:

[image]

[image]

however, no matter how hard I try, it stops here:

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is your node version?, if you press enter when the installation is stuck what happens?.

Comment: First, the version of node is v8.10.0。The installation stopped halfway through，It seems to me that it's permanently stopped at the point of installing the vue cli plugin

Comment: probably your problem is due to the node version, take in account that the last lts in the 8 version is v8.17.0  .  You have Node Version Manager?, if this is the case, please install at least the v8.17.0 with the command  "nvm install v8.17.0 " I test the vue cli command with this version and works perfect.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your solution, I will try and tell you when I have the result

Comment: Now that I have successfully created the project, thank you for your answer